# GFortran not found from make in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

I am trying to set up GFortran in Eclipse. I am using macOS. I installed GFortran and GCC. When I click "build project" in Eclipse I get this error:

```
10:19:28 **** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloFortran ****
make all 
Building file: ../hello.f90
Invoking: GNU Fortran Compiler
gfortran -funderscoring -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "hello.o" "../hello.f90"
/bin/sh: gfortran: command not found
make: *** [hello.o] Error 127
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

10:19:29 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 283ms)
```

I have no idea where to start to fix this. My background is not in computer science. I am trying to learn Fortran for the lab I am joining.

I tried using CLion, but I get the same error in that program also.

This is the output of my terminal that shows that `gcc` and `gfortran` are installed and usable:

```
(base) grantmeadowsjr@Grants-Mac ~ % gcc --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
(base) grantmeadowsjr@Grants-Mac ~ % gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I *very strongly* suggest to avoid starting from an IDE. Crate a very simple program using a text editor and save it. Try using the compiler on the command line of your OS to compile the program. After you make yourself familiar how this works, you can start with an IDE.

Comment: From the error message it seems you either do not have gfortran installed at all or the IDE cannot find it. Tell us what operating system.you have, where and how you installed gfortran, whether you can run it from the command line, and how the IDE is configured.

Comment: According to the terminal it is installed. I used the homebrew port to install it. I am not familiar with with using text editor to compile programs. My coding course only taught us how to use an IDE.

Comment: Demand your money back.

Comment: According to the terminal *how*? Does "make" find it?

Comment: Anyway, you still didn't even mention thaa your OS is MacOS. What version of gfortran do you have? Where it is installed? What exactly does it say in the terminal?

Comment: It looks like Eclipse doesn't grab the user shell environment (bash or zsh depending on your macOS version), and therefore is unaware of the path to find `gfortran`. The first thing to do is to investigate the Eclipse Preferences menu to see what could be set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct path to GFortran in your Makefile.

Like [Vladimir F Героям слава](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721644/vladimir-f-%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0) said, you first need to find out where GFortran is installed. Run

```
which gfortran
```

or

```
type gfortran
```

in your shell. Usual places are `/usr/bin/gfortran` or `/usr/local/bin/gfortran`, but it might be installed somewhere else like under `/opt` or under some macOS specific path. Since your shell can start it, it must know where it is.

Use the path you just found out in your Makefile. If `gfortran` is mentioned directly, then add the full path. If it is not mentioned directly, you need to set the variable `FC` like this:

```
FC := /usr/bin/gfortran
```

Just use your specific full path instead of `/usr/bin/gfortran`.